# Is it possible to create project for developing javascript library with TypeScript in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2019

I would like to use TypeScript for creating javascript library that can be used on web pages. I've seen [tutorials](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-tutorial) / [starter projects](https://github.com/bitjson/typescript-starter) on the web prepared for Visual Studio Code, but cannot find any build-in template in Visual Studio 2019.

Is it possible to develop js lib same way as in Visual Studio Code in Visual Studio 2019?

It Man.

Answer (score 0):

Tutorial explain that you should use Visual Studio Code because you have TSLint and Prettier extensio.

If you want use TSLint on your Visual Studio 2019 you can download this extension:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RichNewman.TypeScriptAnalyzer

Check the GitHub: https://github.com/rich-newman/typescript-analyzer

Comment: What about build configuration and node integration (modules)? Its possible to set it same way?

Comment: In the Gihub Read.me you'll find a lot of informations about configurations and debugging.